# search in complex nested json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i got this json object:

```
var json ="{
   "code":0,
   "aid":"5",
   "data":{
      "39393939":{
         "sport":{
            "88":{
               "region":{
                  "41":{
                     "comp":{
                        "3910":{
                           "game":{
                              "123456":{
                                 "available":1,
                                 "stat":{
                                    "attack":{
                                       "team_1":24,
                                       "team_2":26
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}";
```

im triying to get the value of data.sport.region.comp.game.stat.team_1 value

i tried with loop over data then loop over sport  and loop over region and so on 
with no success.
what is the easy way to do search for : attack.team_1 value without complex loops

thanks

Comment: you should familiarize yourself with recursion

Comment: your json object seems like a string

Comment: prepare more input data in correct json format.

Comment: this json is correct and im geting it from socket , this json is valid but i cannot think of way to get attack values, thanks for your comments, im still stuck on that

Comment: try `JSON.parse(yourJson)` before you get the values

Comment: my issue is after i did JSON.parse and try to get the value i need, on each static key there is a dynamic value and sub value under the key and thats what make it complex